# Windows Authentication, FBA and Anonymous users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, anonymous-authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to setup FBA for a SharePoint 2013 WebApplication which has Windows Authentication and Anonymous users enabled. Will these three: FBA, Windows Authentication & Anonymous users work together?

Furthermore, can I change the text of the choices shown in dropdown of the login page when FBA is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with having multiple authentications provider in a single web application and single zone. You can have windows, FBA, Trusted identity provider and basic authentication.

If anonymous enabled than no body will be prompted and all anonymous content will be visible, but for the secure area you will see sign in page and user will click on it to get in.

You can customize your sign in page, but mostly what ever name you mentioned while configuring your authentication will be appear in drop down.

[Read this msdn article which will help you.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2014/10/31/bypassing-multiple-authentication-providers-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enable multiple authentication options enabled for a specific web application. As a result you can work with multiple authentication options (e.g Windows, FBA, Custom) for your sites

Yes, you can customize your login component by creating custom sign-in page